# Best practice for cleaning Pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am cleaning str columns in a Pandas dataframe (see below for an example), and I have been wondering if there are more concise ways or additional inplace methods to do so. What are the general best practices for cleaning columns in Pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"col1": [0, 1, 2, 3], "col2": ["abcd efg", ".%ues", "t12 ^&3", "yupe"]})

df["col2"] = df["col2"].str.lower()
df["col2"] = df["col2"].str.strip()
df["col2"].replace(to_replace="[^a-zA-Z ]", value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not too bad. It's a good thing you use keyword arguments for the `replace method`

I always try to keep my original data in its original state, and continue with the cleaned dataframe.

## fluent style

This lends itself very well to a kind of fluent style as in [this example](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/master/docs/the_black_code_style.md#call-chains). I use it too, and use a lot of `df.assign`, `df.pipe`, `df.query`...

In this example I would do something like

```
df_cleaned = df.assign(
    col2=(
        df["col2"]
        .str.lower()
        .str.strip()
        .replace(to_replace="[^a-zA-Z ]", value="", regex=True)
    )
)
```

So definately no `inplace` replacements